# Submitting form in symfony2 (ManyToOne)

Tags: forms, symfony, doctrine-orm

Sorry in advance for my bad level in english.

I am working on a symfony2 project for 3 weeks (I’m a beginner on symfony2) and I have a problem about one update form.

My form use two entity : one called PIECE and one called MARQUE.

The entity PIECE contains a field of type MARQUE (relation ManyToOne).

The problem is that, when I submit this form to update an object of PIECE, all fields are updated correctly, but the content of the object MARQUE (in relation with the object PIECE) is also updated by the new value, which I don’t want to.

I just want to update the content of the field MARQUE in my PIECE object, and not update the content of my field NAME in MARQUE.

With this code, I got the same MARQUE two times in my database (note that it's not all the code):

```
if ($form->isValid()) {

    if ($tmp == 0) { //if MARQUE is not submit/doesn't exist, i create a new one and I link it to PIECE
        $piece->setMarque($nouvelleMarque);
    } else if ($tmp == 1) { // if MARQUE exist in database, I just link it to PIECE 
        $piece->setMarque($marque);
    }
    $em->persist($piece->getMarque());
    $em->persist($piece);
    $em->flush();
}
```

Edit: Here the definition of the entity PIECE:

```
/**
* Piece
*
* @ORM\Table()
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Symfony\StockBundle\Entity\PieceRepository")
*/
class Piece
{
    /**
    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Symfony\StockBundle\Entity\Marque")
    * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true)
    * @Assert\Valid()
    */
    private $marque;
```

Comment: Can you show us the `PIECE` entity definition?

Comment: Of course, I edited my original post. I just paste the few lines who are interesting here (because the file is about 300 lines).

Comment: What if you remove `$em->persist($piece->getMarque());`. Do you persist/flush the new `MARQUE ` somewhere when it is the case? Why don't you use `cascade`?

Comment: If I remove this line the same problem appear.

Comment: Where do `$nouvelleMarque` and `$marque` come from ?

Comment: $nouvelleMarque is an object of MARQUE which i create before validation of this form. It's created only if the user had enter a MARQUE name who it's not already in database. 
$marque is an object of MARQUE which contains the MARQUE entered by the user. It's created only if user had enter a MARQUE name which is in database. (these two thing works in my code)

Comment: What if you take `$em->persist($piece->getMarque());` out and use [`$em->detach($piece->getMarque());`](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/working-with-objects.html#detaching-entities) instead?

Comment: Thank you so much dude, you litterraly saved my life :)
I just need to put it after this line $form->bind($request); before validation

Comment: Still weird that you have to call `detach` even when not using `cascade` but, if it works... :)